# Can I implement robot path planning using hill climbing algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, hill-climbing

I want to implement the robot path planning program applying hill climbing algorithm.

I understand the basic of hill climbing algorithm but I cannot think any idea!

I also Googled the hill climbing algorithm, but I cannot find any information about robot path planning with hill climbing algorithm.

It is hard to implement start function, choosing neighbor function, and check/draw path using Bresenham's line algorithm.

Comment: I think Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm might be a better choice: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm

Comment: Oh.... I already tried and finished Dijikstra's path algorithm.

Answer (score -2):

It all depends on which pathfinding algorithm you are using of course, but essentially just add a multiplier to the amount of 'cost' associated with hill climbing. Something as simple as:

```
//Psuedo-code
MovementCost = FlatDistance + (HillClimbAltitude * 2)
//Where 2 is the 'effort' involved in climbing compared to a flat distance
```

Would suffice. This also easily accomodates for a cost reduction where a hill decline (downhill) is involved. You could fancy it up by making the cost increase based on the angle of the incline etc

Comment: I think the OP is asking about [hill climbing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing), and not literally how to use pathfinding algorithm to climb a hill.